# Can shipping companies be held liable for consequential damages?

Tags: liability, shipping

I sent some goods in bulk to a client worth a lot of money from India and UPS delivered the good 20 days later than the expected delivery date causing a major loss for my business as the client cancelled the order.  Do I have any claim against them for those damages?

Comment: Did you take out an insurance policy with UPS? If so, file a claim against that. If not, it could be hard. Either way, this will likely be closed as seeking specific legal advice, which should be sought from a lawyer, not random people on the internet. I'd suggest you talk to local attorneys.

Answer (score 1):

### No

Under your [contract](https://www.ups.com/assets/resources/media/terms_service_us.pdf#page32) with UPS (Clause 55.2):

> UNDER NO CIRCUMSTANCES SHALL UPS BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, INCIDENTAL, OR CONSE­QUENTIAL DAMAGES ...